# Pyodbc connection with amazon rds postgres database produces error when executing SQL commands (syntax error)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, python-3.7, pyodbc

I have set up a connection between pyodbc and the aws rds (postgresql database) and have installed psqlodbc (which is what the Postgres Unicode(x64) odbc driver is). Everything looks fine until I run a SQL query. It returns a syntax error but there is nothing wrong with my syntax. I'm not exactly sure what would be the issue.

This is Python 3.7 by the way.

```
import pyodbc

mypw = 'skjhaf234234dkjhkjx'
string = 'Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=myfakeserveraddress.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=mydb;UID=myusername;PWD='+mypw+';'
connection = pyodbc.connect(string)
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM schema_table.test_table;")
```

Error Message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42601', '[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "'schema_table.test_table'";\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Without the single quotation marks `'` surrounding the table name, I get this error

```
c.execute("SELECT * from schema_table.test_table")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('25P02', '[25P02] ERROR: current
> transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
> block;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')

PS My company has disabled pip installs so I cannot upgrade my packages and am limited to using only a few packages (including this one).

How can I execute my commands without errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have figured it out.... I added autocommit=False to the connection initialization and it seems fine now.... Perhaps it has something to do with the underlying parsing of the sql commands. Keeping the question in case it helps someone.

```
import pyodbc

mypw = 'skjhaf234234dkjhkjx'
string = 'Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=myfakeserveraddress.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=mydb;UID=myusername;PWD='+mypw+';'
connection = pyodbc.connect(string, autocommit=False)
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM schema_table.test_table;")
```